# ASP.Net Core Controller Outer Join to return all records

Tags: sql-server, rest, linq, asp.net-core

I have a linq query as follows and I would like to return records even if the "OrderItems" table is null

My Code

```
var query = from order in DbContext.JobOrders.Where(i => i.Status == 1 && i.Facility == roleID.First().Facility)
                            where order.OrderStat == apiID

                            join users in DbContext.users on order.Uid equals users.Uid into onlineusers
                            from onusers in onlineusers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join customers in DbContext.customers on order.Uid equals customers.Uid into offlinecustomers
                            from offusers in offlinecustomers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join oi in DbContext.OrderItems on order.Eid equals oi.OrderId
                            group oi by new { order.Eid, order.Uid, order.OrderStat, order.Date, order.CollectionSlot, Name = onusers.Name == null ? offusers.Name : onusers.Name, Contact = onusers.Contact == null ? offusers.Contact : onusers.Contact } into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Eid = g.Key.Eid,
                                Uid = g.Key.Uid,
                                OrderStat = g.Key.OrderStat,
                                Orderdate = g.Key.Date,
                                CollectionSlot = g.Key.CollectionSlot,
                                Name = g.Key.Name,
                                Contact = g.Key.Contact,
                                Qty = g.Sum(x => x.Qty),
                            };


                var result = query.OrderByDescending(m => m.Eid).ToList();

                return Ok(result);
```

I would like to return all records from table "JobOrders" even if there is no related entry in table "OrderItems".

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should almost never use JOIN in LINQ to Entities.  Instead simply follow your navigation properties in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by adding DefaultIfEmpty(), my new code

```
var query = from order in DbContext.JobOrders.Where(i => i.Status == 1 && i.Facility == roleID.First().Facility)
                            where order.OrderStat == apiID

                            join users in DbContext.users on order.Uid equals users.Uid into onlineusers
                            from onusers in onlineusers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join customers in DbContext.customers on order.Uid equals customers.Uid into offlinecustomers
                            from offusers in offlinecustomers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join oi in DbContext.OrderItems on order.Eid equals oi.OrderId  into prefinaldata
                            from predata in prefinaldata.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            group predata by new { order.Eid, order.Uid, order.OrderStat, order.Date, order.CollectionSlot, Name = onusers.Name == null ? offusers.Name : onusers.Name, Contact = onusers.Contact == null ? offusers.Contact : onusers.Contact } into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Eid = g.Key.Eid,
                                Uid = g.Key.Uid,
                                OrderStat = g.Key.OrderStat,
                                Orderdate = g.Key.Date,
                                CollectionSlot = g.Key.CollectionSlot,
                                Name = g.Key.Name,
                                Contact = g.Key.Contact,
                                Qty = g.Sum(x => x.Qty),
                            };


                var result = query.OrderByDescending(m => m.Eid).ToList();

                return Ok(result);
```